# Query Mysql with start date have different value base on other table

Tags: mysql, sql

### I have 2 tables in MySQL: city & user

here is the user table

| city | date | user |
| --- | --- | --- |
| jkt | 2021-10-15 | 10 |
| jkt | 2021-10-16 | 3 |
| jkt | 2021-10-17 | 0 |
| jkt | 2021-10-18 | 9 |
| jkt | 2021-10-19 | 15 |
| jkt | 2021-10-20 | 15 |
| jkt | 2021-10-21 | 15 |
| jbi | 2021-10-15 | 12 |
| jbi | 2021-10-16 | 4 |
| jbi | 2021-10-17 | 5 |
| jbi | 2021-10-18 | 2 |
| jbi | 2021-10-19 | 8 |
| jbi | 2021-10-20 | 13 |
| jbi | 2021-10-21 | 10 |

and the city table
city |      start_date     |
-----| ---------------|
jkt | 2021-10-17    |
jbi | 2021-10-19    |

I would like to select user & city with start date base on start_date at city table. this is an example result.

| city | date | user |
| --- | --- | --- |
| jkt | 2021-10-17 | 0 |
| jkt | 2021-10-18 | 9 |
| jkt | 2021-10-19 | 15 |
| jkt | 2021-10-20 | 15 |
| jkt | 2021-10-21 | 15 |
| jbi | 2021-10-19 | 8 |
| jbi | 2021-10-20 | 13 |
| jbi | 2021-10-21 | 10 |

I already query  `select city.city, date, user from city inner join user on city.city=user.city`
but stils I have no idea how to create condition with start date due to each city have different start date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the start date of the city dynamically:

```
select city.city, `date`, `user`
from city
join `user`
on city.city = `user`.city and
   `user`.`date` >= city.start_date
```